# awkward monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Solving a problem from Google Code Jam ([2009.1A.A: "Multi-base happiness"](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=188266#s=p0)) I came up with an awkward (code-wise) solution, and I'm interested in how it could be improved.

The problem description, shortly, is: Find the smallest number bigger than 1 for which iteratively calculating the sum of squares of digits reaches 1, for all bases from a given list.

Or description in pseudo-Haskell (code that would solve it if `elem` could always work for infinite lists):

```
solution =
  head . (`filter` [2..]) .
  all ((1 `elem`) . (`iterate` i) . sumSquareOfDigitsInBase)
```

And my awkward solution:

- By awkward I mean it has this kind of code: `happy <- lift . lift . lift $ isHappy Set.empty base cur`
- I memoize results of the isHappy function. Using the State monad for the memoized results Map.
- Trying to find the first solution, I did not use `head` and `filter` (like the pseudo-haskell above does), because the computation isn't pure (changes state). So I iterated by using StateT with a counter, and a MaybeT to terminate the computation when condition holds.
- Already inside a `MaybeT (StateT a (State b))`, if the condition doesn't hold for one base, there is no need to check the other ones, so I have another `MaybeT` in the stack for that.

Code:

```
import Control.Monad.Maybe
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type IsHappyMemo = State (Map.Map (Integer, Integer) Bool)

isHappy :: Set.Set Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> IsHappyMemo Bool
isHappy _ _ 1 = return True
isHappy path base num = do
  memo <- get
  case Map.lookup (base, num) memo of
    Just r -> return r
    Nothing -> do
      r <- calc
      when (num < 1000) . modify $ Map.insert (base, num) r
      return r
  where
    calc
      | num `Set.member` path = return False
      | otherwise = isHappy (Set.insert num path) base nxt
    nxt =
      sum . map ((^ (2::Int)) . (`mod` base)) .
      takeWhile (not . (== 0)) . iterate (`div` base) $ num

solve1 :: [Integer] -> IsHappyMemo Integer
solve1 bases =
  fmap snd .
  (`runStateT` 2) .
  runMaybeT .
  forever $ do
    (`when` mzero) . isJust =<<
      runMaybeT (mapM_ f bases)
    lift $ modify (+ 1)
  where
    f base = do
      cur <- lift . lift $ get
      happy <- lift . lift . lift $ isHappy Set.empty base cur
      unless happy mzero

solve :: [String] -> String
solve =
  concat .
  (`evalState` Map.empty) .
  mapM f .
  zip [1 :: Integer ..]
  where
    f (idx, prob) = do
      s <- solve1 . map read . words $ prob
      return $ "Case #" ++ show idx ++ ": " ++ show s ++ "\n"

main :: IO ()
main =
  getContents >>=
  putStr . solve . tail . lines
```

Other contestants using Haskell did have [nicer solutions](http://www.go-hero.net/jam/09/solutions/1/1/Haskell), but solved the problem differently. My question is about small iterative improvements to my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is certainly awkward in its use (and abuse) of monads:

- It is usual to build monads piecemeal by stacking several transformers
- It is less usual, but still happens sometimes, to stack several states
- It is very unusual to stack several Maybe transformers
- It is even more unusual to use MaybeT to interrupt a loop

Your code is a bit too pointless :

```
(`when` mzero) . isJust =<<
   runMaybeT (mapM_ f bases)
```

instead of the easier to read

```
let isHappy = isJust $ runMaybeT (mapM_ f bases)
when isHappy mzero
```

Focusing now on function solve1, let us simplify it.
An easy way to do so is to remove the inner MaybeT monad. Instead of a forever loop which breaks when a happy number is found, you can go the other way around and recurse only if the 
number is not happy.

Moreover, you don't really need the State monad either, do you ? One can always replace the state with an explicit argument.

Applying these ideas solve1 now looks much better:

```
solve1 :: [Integer] -> IsHappyMemo Integer
solve1 bases = go 2 where
  go i = do happyBases <- mapM (\b -> isHappy Set.empty b i) bases
            if and happyBases
              then return i
              else go (i+1)
```

I would be more han happy with that code.
The rest of your solution is fine.
One thing that bothers me is that you throw away the memo cache for every subproblem. Is there a reason for that?

```
solve :: [String] -> String
 solve =
    concat .
    (`evalState` Map.empty) .
    mapM f .
   zip [1 :: Integer ..]
  where
    f (idx, prob) = do
      s <- solve1 . map read . words $ prob
      return $ "Case #" ++ show idx ++ ": " ++ show s ++ "\n"
```

Wouldn't your solution be more efficient if you reused it instead ?

```
solve :: [String] -> String
solve cases = (`evalState` Map.empty) $ do
   solutions <- mapM f (zip [1 :: Integer ..] cases)
   return (unlines solutions)
  where
    f (idx, prob) = do
      s <- solve1 . map read . words $ prob
      return $ "Case #" ++ show idx ++ ": " ++ show s
```

Comment: @pepeiborra: great answer but I think there's some problems. imho I don't throw away the memo cache like you say. you can return "solutions" instead of "unlines solutions" and apply "unlines" to evalState's result. then instead of doing "solution <- ...; return solutions" you can just do "...". that's what I'm doing.. also, you calculate isHappy in all bases even if one has returned False..

Comment: Right, I didn't pay enough attention, your code does not throw away the memo cache.
Reg. all bases, the State monad is lazy by default, so only those bases which are really needed should be calculated.

Comment: @pepeiborra: reg. all bases, I don't think the State monad's lazyness solves it. this still affects the state and in the next time the state is needed (next invocation of solve1) those computations will need to be made to calculate it.

Comment: @yairchu there are two things going on here. 

One, since the default State monad is lazy, the effect of the computation (updating the state) is suspended until it is really needed. In this case, the state is actually needed the next time solve1 is invocated, so yes, those isHappy calls in the rest of bases take place.

But two, since the state itself is lazy, as Data.Map is lazy in the values (and strict in the keys, I believe), those additional calls to isHappy are suspended and never get a chance to run unless really needed.

Comment: @yairchu another attempt, this time with code: http://www.hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=9612

Answer (score 4):

The Monad* classes exist to remove the need for repeated lifting. If you change your signatures like this:

```
type IsHappyMemo = Map.Map (Integer, Integer) Bool

isHappy :: MonadState IsHappyMemo m => Set.Set Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> m Bool
```

This way you can remove most of the 'lift's. However, the longest sequence of lifts cannot be removed, since it is a State monad inside a StateT, so using the MonadState type class will give you the outer StateT, where you need tot get to the inner State. You could wrap your State monad in a newtype and make a MonadHappy class, similar to the existing monad classes.

Answer (score 0):

`ListT` (from the [List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/List) package) does a much nicer job than `MaybeT` in stopping the calculation when necessary.

```
solve1 :: [Integer] -> IsHappyMemo Integer
solve1 bases = do
  Cons result _ <- runList . filterL cond $ fromList [2..]
  return result
  where
    cond num = andL . mapL (isHappy Set.empty num) $ fromList bases
```

#### Some elaboration on how this works:

Had we used a regular list the code would had looked like this:

```
solve1 bases = do
  result:_ <- filterM cond [2..]
  return result
  where
    cond num = fmap and . mapM (isHappy Set.empty num) bases
```

This calculation happens in a `State` monad, but if we'd like to get the resulting state, we'd have a problem, because `filterM` runs the monadic predicate it gets for every element of `[2..]`, an infinite list.

With the monadic list, `filterL cond (fromList [2..])` represents a list that we can access one item at a time as a monadic action, so our monadic predicate `cond` isn't actually executed (and affecting the state) unless we consume the corresponding list items.

Similarly, implementing `cond` using `andL` makes us not calculate and update the state if we already got a `False` result from one of the `isHappy Set.empty num` calculations.

Comment: Could you explain more, how the calculation can be "stopped"?